# Breakpoints not working with Flutter in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, breakpoints

I can set breakpoints, but when I run in Debug mode the breakpoint's icon change with this:

[image]

I think that the problem is the new version of Flutter plugin in Android Studio, but I'm not sure. How to fix this?

What I've tried:

1. flutter clean
2. android studio cache clean and restart

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of the flutter plugin **65.1.3 solved my problem.**

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/versions

Comment: Thanks, It's solved my issue. It's very poor from flutter team.

Answer (score 9):

need to roll back the version of the flutter plugin to 64.1.2.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/versions

Comment: You've saved my day!

Comment: Can you please share, how to roll back to old version ? How to install the old version plugin. ?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/6002#issuecomment-1057531877

Comment: This seems still true as of 01.06.2022....

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed: plug-in was one thing.

The other problem is that IntelliJ (same for Android Studio) distinguish between:

```
import '../../viewmodel/**m**essages
import '../../viewmodel/**M**essages
```

Compiling, running, Dart analysis ... everything's fine. However, breakpoints don't work!

To be more precise: some breakpoints don't work, only in some files!

Tip: If a breakpoint does not work, remove all imports in the file. Click the bulb to get suggestions - and you will see the duplicate imports.
[See wrong imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DftvV.png)

Btw.: I am on Windows. And the file system does not distinguish between upper and lower case filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Faced to this issue today as well: looks like for me the solution was to update Flutter / Dart SDK and their Plugins for Android Studio.

Some users report the problem is linked to the Chrom Version >=100 due to API change, but on my side it was not working with Edge as well.

After update problem has gone

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed also an issue with Chrome Version >=100.  Running `flutter upgrade` (to flutter 2.10.5) fixed this for me as described [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101224)